# Need help stripping a section from a .so

Tags: llvm

I need some help with llvm-strip / llvm-objcopy.

I've built a shared object, using -fembed-bitcode. When looking into it, it has a section .llvmbc which I would like to strip (I know, I could just remove the flag, but this is an example for learning :))

Using llvm-strip, I'm able to use --remove-section to remove the .llvmbc section, but that doesn't seems to remove the bitcode from the .so, as the size doesn't change. What I would like, is for the bitcode to be removed, similar to how debug symbols can be stripped out of the .so, but I couldn't figure out a way to do this. I also tried with llvm-objcopy but I get the same behavior.

Is there any option that I'm missing in llvm-strip or llvm-objcopy ? Or do I need to use another tool to do this ?

Thanks !